# Стоит ли выделять запятыми слово "так"

Tags: правописание

В данном случае:"Так,сколько здесь еще любителей сыра?"

Answer (score 2):

Вполне возможно и с запятой. Стоит только изменить интонацию.

Comment: Я вроде бы комментарий писала.

Answer (score 1):

1) Так. Сколько здесь ещё любителей сыра? (Усилительная частица (с точкой или запятой), призванная привлечь внимание слушателей к говорящему). 2) Так сколько здесь ещё любителей сыра? (промежуточное слово, с помощью которого оттеняется повторность вопроса). Вопрос с неоднозначным ответом: возможны варианты и 1), и 2).

Comment: Для строгого решения надо указать часть речи, так как  у нас нет термина "промежуточное слово". Возможно, это "частиц-вводное слово" со значением повторности вопроса при отсутствии обособления  или "частица-междометие", если она выражает разнообразные(неназываемые конкретно) чувства при обособлении.

Comment: Согласен с Вами, но к строгому решению не готов.

Answer (score 0):

В данном предложении запятая не нужна, ибо слово "так" является частицей, а не вводным словом

Comment: Виктор прав: ТАК является частицей, запятая не нужна. Чтобы поставить запятую, нужно переделать предложение:"Итак,сколько здесь еще любителей сыра?" Слово ТАК может являться вводным словом, но оно в этом случае имеет значение "например". Интересен еще редкий вариант с обособленной частицей ТАК: "Сошелся со мной один пропащий совсем человек. Так, в харчевне сошлись".

Comment: ТА-а-к -  интонация удивления, застали на месте "преступления": сидят поздно вечером, например, и сыр едят. Мама зашла на кухню: "Та-ак, сколько здесь еще любителей сыра?" Я это предложение сразу таким увидела, с логическим ударением на "ещё". Почему нет?

Comment: Такой вариант вполне возможен. Из этого следует сделать вывод, что слово ТАК может выступать в роли междометия, причем с разными значениями. (Даже лучше считать ТАК междометием, так как частицы мы не должны обособлять). А междометия выражают РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ чувства и отношения, не называя их, и при этом обособляются интонационно и на письме.

Answer (score 0):

> но оно в этом случае имеет значение "например"

Но в этом значении оно должно обособляться. Это же вводное слово?

Comment: Слово ТАК в значении НАПРИМЕР: "Его скопидомство доходило до крайности: так(=например), он целый год писал одним пером". В этом случае мы высказываем какое-то суждение, а затем доказываем или распространяем его.

Answer (score 0):

"Вполне возможно и с запятой. Стоит только изменить интонацию". Это верный ответ.

Comment: Это начало верного ответа. Здесь как в математике: вы называете ответ, а вас просят объяснить ваше решение. Так что для ответа надо указать, какой частью речи является слово ТАК и какое оно имеет значение в обособленном и необособленном варианте.

Comment: Объясняю решение.
Если "так" является частицей (скорее всего, эмоционально-экспрессивной, хотя утверждать не берусь), то запятую не ставим.
Если "так" является вводным словом со значением указания на связь мыслей ("так"="кстати"), то запятую ставим.

Comment: Вы приводите общую  формулировку правила. У нас же есть конкретный пример, в котором мы ставим или не ставим запятую. Нужно определить грамматический статус слова ТАК и  значение для каждого случая. Например: вводным словом в нашем случае ТАК не назовешь, это, скорее, нечто среднее между указательным значением слова ТАК и значением "повторности вопроса, подведения итога". Связь мыслей, на которую вы указываете, - это слишком общее определение. А какие конкретно эмоции слово выражает? И т.д. Согласитесь, ваш первый ответ мало что добавил к прояснению всех вопросов, которые здесь обсуждались.

Comment: Попробую от себя подвести итог. Необособленный вариант: "ТАК" - частица со значением вводного (итогового)слова. Эмоций здесь нет. Таким же образом можно спросить: "Так сколько  я тебе должен?" Обособленный вариант: "ТАК" - частица-междометие, значение указательности слова совмещено с выражением эмоциональной оценки ситуации.